# Why does puts() have a random trailing character when using a pointer only for certain values

Tags: c++

This is the code
I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot pin down what it is exactly.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  int n = 8;
  char * string = new char[n];
 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
  {
    string[i] = '#';
  }
  puts(pointer);

  delete [] pointer;
  return 0;
}
```

For n < 8, I do not run into any issues.

Output for n = 7.

`#######`

However, when I increase n over 7, it begins to error.
When run multiple times the last character changes, here I represent that with 'A'
Output for n = 8,9,10,11.

`########X☺A`

`#########☺A`

`##########A`

`###########`

This was confusing, so I wrote a general case. n 0-> 100. I still don't get what is happening.

[image: staircase of increasing n values]

If you know how I can fix my code, and or why this is happening that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of a "string" is and how it differs from an array of characters?

Comment: This is c++, not c.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is what's happening.

Comment: I guess the better question is this -- how are you expecting `puts` to know how many characters to print? Why do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a trailing '\0', and the buffer must have room for it.

code should be:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  int n = 8;
  char * pointer = new char[n+1];
 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
  {
    pointer[i] = '#';
  }
  pointer[n] = '\0';// note this here, this is the line that does the work
  puts(pointer);

  delete [] pointer;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `pointer[n]`. The last valid array element is `pointer[n-1]`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The code was just edited to correct that.

Comment: I don't like this. `new char[n]` is good. You should change the loop and the null termination.